# How do I divide a time (h:mm:ss) by a pace (h:mm:ss/mile) to get a distance in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating a song list for an upcoming marathon, and I'm hoping to know exactly how far I will be at certain points in the race when a particular song comes on.  (Assuming I can maintain a steady pace of course!)

To that end, I've got a column showing how long each song is (for example, Cell A2 is 0:03:50), and another column with a pace in min/mile (Cell B2 is 0:08:50).  I would like to be able to divide the first time, A2, by the pace in B2 to get a distance in miles calculated in C2.

I've searched far and wide, but I think I'm the only guy trying to calculate distance as opposed to calculating a pace based on distance and time.  It should be easy to go backwards, but I'm not as proficient in excel as I need to be to pull this off.

Comment: Could you please check the cell format of A2 and B2 (Right click on A2 or B2 > Format Cells)?
Have you entered formula `=A2/B2` in C2? If so, what are results you get?

Comment: Thanks so much Emily and for everyone who helped. I had already tried dividing cell A2 by B2, and I was getting some sort of error I couldn't interpret. The problem ended up being that I was using an Excel spreadsheet that had formatting that wasn't apparent to me as I was plugging in numbers. I tried opening up a new spreadsheet with 0 formatting and that did the trick. Thanks so much for everybody's contributions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel times are stored as numbers, with a format applied to them that tells that they represent time values.

To divide A2 by B2, input the following in C2:

```
=A2/B2
```

Comment: You might wish to be more helpful; tell that the "Number" has an integer portion representing days. The fraction (decimals) tells how much of a day that is included.